# Word Wrap text in Out-Gridview

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

using powershell out-grid view. Is there a way to wrap text so the user doesn't have to scroll to see everything?

```
Invoke-RestMethod -uri "https://clasd.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets? email=xyz@clasd.net" -Headers $FDHeaders -ContentType application/json -Method Get |
    Convertto-json | Out-File C:\csiu\test.txt
$file = "C:\csiu\test.txt"
$data = Get-Content $file -Raw |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    Select-Object -Expand Value $data |
    Select id, subject, description_text |
    Sort-Object ID |
    Out-GridView -Title "My Tickets" -passthru
```

Just wish out-grid view wrapped the text

Or if there is another way to display the data "prettier" I'm all for it.

**Update**

I've been playing around with the datagrid and it's actually working. The only thing is the columns aren't the correct size, or they don't resize on their own. The column in question concerns the description_text.

```
#Generated Form Function
function GenerateForm {
    ########################################################################
    # Code Generated By: SAPIEN Technologies PrimalForms (Community Edition) v1.0.8.0
    # Generated On: 4/6/2013 3:10 PM
    # Generated By: jvierra
    ########################################################################

    #region Import the Assemblies
    [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
    [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
    #endregion

    #region Generated Form Objects
    $form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $dataGrid1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid
    $InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState
    #endregion Generated Form Objects

    #----------------------------------------------
    #Generated Event Script Blocks
    #----------------------------------------------
    #Provide Custom Code for events specified in PrimalForms.
    $button1_OnClick= {
    #TODO: Place custom script here

    }
# API Key
$FDApiKey="key"
#################################################

# Force TLS1.2 as Powershell defaults to TLS 1.0 and Freshdesk will fail connections 
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::TLS12

# Prep
$pair = "$($FDApiKey):$($FDApiKey)"
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair)
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $base64"
$FDHeaders = @{ Authorization = $basicAuthValue }
##################################################

<#$Body = @{
description = $description.Text
email = $email.Text
subject = $subject.Text
type = $request.Text
priority = 1
status = 2
}#>

Invoke-RestMethod -uri "https://clasd.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets?email=mgirt@clasd.net&order_by=status" -Headers $FDHeaders -ContentType application/json -Method Get | Convertto-json | Out-File c:\temp\mytickets.txt
$file = "c:\temp\mytickets.txt"
$data = Get-Content $file -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -Expand Value


    $handler_form1_Load= 
    {
    $list=[system.collections.arraylist]($data | select id, subject, description_text)
    $datagrid1.DataSource=$list

    }

    $OnLoadForm_StateCorrection=
    {#Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
        $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
    }

    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Form Code
    $form1.Text = "My Tickets"
    $form1.Name = "form1"
    $form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 616
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 312
    $form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
    $form1.add_Load($handler_form1_Load)

    $button1.TabIndex = 1
    $button1.Name = "button1"
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 75
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
    $button1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $False

    $button1.Text = "Ok"

    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 507
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 469
    $button1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $button1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $button1.DialogResult = 1
    $button1.add_Click($button1_OnClick)

    $form1.Controls.Add($button1)

    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 600
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 433
    $dataGrid1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $dataGrid1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $dataGrid1.HeaderForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,0,0,0)
    $dataGrid1.Name = "dataGrid1"
    $dataGrid1.DataMember = ""
    $dataGrid1.TabIndex = 0
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 1
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 12
    $dataGrid1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point

    $form1.Controls.Add($dataGrid1)

    #endregion Generated Form Code

    #Save the initial state of the form
    $InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
    #Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
    $form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
    #Show the Form
    $form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

} #End Function

#Call the Function
GenerateForm
```

Comment: I don't believe that `Out-GridView` can wrap, but I believe the WinForm `DataGridView` control can. (Which is way less convenient as you'll have to design your own Form)

Comment: Along with @BenH, you could also do a wpf form and customize your datagrid to however you would like to see it using xaml.

Comment: Seems complicated.

Comment: [See this on the topic](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/edf7c616-a201-4076-8025-b9ef02bcbd0e/wrap-text-in-grid-column-of-outgridview?forum=winserverpowershell)

Comment: @LotPings That works wonderfully. Now to go off that, I wonder if there is a way to just auto size the whole form based off of the results.